# In Java FutureTask if the task Times out, does the Task get Cancelled?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, futuretask

Assuming I have the following code snippet:

```
FutureTask<?> f = new FutureTask<>(() -> { Thread.sleep(5000); return 1 + 2; })

myExecutor.execute(f);
f.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

From what is coded, the last line will fail after 3 seconds with `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`

**My question is: Does the actual work inside future continue to get executed? Or it does it get cancelled? Could I, later, after another 2 seconds, retrieve the actual result, or is it gone?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It continues to be executed.

By adding a second `f.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` you can retrieve the result:

```
Object o2 = f.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("o2 = " + o2); // prints o2 = 3
```

You can try to cancel the calculation by calling

```
f.cancel(true);
```

Then, when retrieving the object with

```
Object o2 = f.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

it throws a `CancellationException`

Answer (score 0):

> Does the actual work inside future continue to executed?

Yes.The task execution will be in progress unless you cancel it.

> Or it does it get cancelled?

No. It won't cancelled unless you cancel it.

> Could I, later, after another 2 seconds, retrieve the actual result, or is it gone?

Yes. You can get result later even after time-out.

Have a look at sample code snippet:

Below code get the status of future after 3 seconds time-out. I have created artificial delay to demonstrate the example.  In real time, the output will be different in absence of `sleep()` methods.

```
public class FutureTaskQuery {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        Future future = executor.submit(new MyCallable());
        try{
            Integer result = (Integer)future.get(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }catch(TimeoutException e){
            System.out.println("Time out after 3 seconds");
            //future.cancel(true);
        }catch(InterruptedException ie){
            System.out.println("Error: Interrupted");
        }catch(ExecutionException ee){
            System.out.println("Error: Execution interrupted");
        }   
        try{
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            Integer result = (Integer)future.get(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            System.out.println("Result:"+result);
        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}

class MyCallable implements Callable<Integer>{
    public Integer call(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 2;
    }
}
```

output:

```
Time out after 3 seconds
Result:2
```

If you un-comment below line

```
future.cancel(true);
```

output:

```
Time out after 3 seconds
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at MyCallable.call(FutureTaskQuery.java:31)
        at MyCallable.call(FutureTaskQuery.java:28)
```